# Sql Query Performance String Contains vs Unique Key?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have this table in my SQL Server database which has a few million rows. It stores pictures with urls. There are new pictures being added constantly and I don't want to have duplicated urls. So each time from my C# code I do linq query something like;

```
!pictures.Any(n => n.url == url)
```

or

```
!pictures.Contains(n => n.url == url)
```

So both of them increases the DTU of the database a lot especially on the CPU level. So I have to use higher tier in Azure Database service as well.

My question is, if I make the `url` column in the table a unique column or composite primary key and have my insert to db code in C# around try catch block, would it be better? Would it increase the performance of the query and database? Or is there better way to do that?

My main query is:

```
var existingImage = _context.Pictures.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Body.Trim().ToLower() == pictureUrl.Trim().ToLower() && p.AppId == appId);
```

where AppId is primary key.

Comment: use a GUID as the primary key - that would give you uniqueness with a high-degree of certainty. The primary key would then be the filename within the file system.

Comment: I'm no DBA, but a unique key would on `url` should be much faster than a scan. Generally using try/catch for logic is not good practice but sometimes it is justified. Also consider just indexing the column. You can inspect execution plans under the various scenarios to make decisions about which way to go.

Comment: @Crowcoder column is already indexed but having so much data not really helps. It is also string field with long values. That's why I'm looking for alternative solutions and thinking of giving this one a shot.

Comment: @erincerol, from what you've mentioned, no need for a composite or surrogate key.  A primary key on url alone should suffice.  If the column is already indexed, it seems the SQL being sent does not have the needed `WHERE` clause or the query is doing a scan for some other reason.  Post the `CREATE TABLE` and actual query being sent.

Comment: Where do these URLs come from? Is there a guaranteed max length you can assume?

Comment: @DanGuzman Ok, I will check that.

Comment: @MartinSmith urls are coming randomly from different sources. They are not necessarily max length but there usually quite long ones.

Comment: If they can exceed `varchar(900)` you won't be able to create a unique index on them anyway. You could consider hashing and creating a non unique index on the hash - then checking the full url for any matching that hash.

Comment: Do you create the URLs and are trying to avoid creating duplicate URLs for the pictures? If so, Martin's suggestion on storing a hash of the URLs is most optimal but you need to create a unique index on that hash column. That way, when you create new URLs (insert new rows?), the unique constraint will fail the query if the hashes collide.

Comment: @sqlmo A unique constraint on the hash could reject valid non duplicates because of hash collisions.

Comment: Yes but the odds are very low with any common hash algorithms (all bets are off for home grown stuff). Also, when a false positive on collision occurs, you can then initiate the more expensive URL comparison for a definitive validation.

Comment: @SQLmojoe urls are coming from so many different sources with different host names different urls etc. Basically I have this:            
    ```var existingImage = _context.Pictures.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Body.Trim().ToLower() == pictureUrl.Trim().ToLower() && p.AppId == appId);``` where appid is primary key

Comment: @DanGuzman I have added the query code

Comment: @MartinSmith I have added the query code.

Comment: @SQLmojoe - "Initiating the  more expensive URL comparison" isn't going to help any because even if it results in the conclusion that the urls are in fact different the **unique** index you propose on the hash won't let them be saved anyway.